# ( Prestashop 1.7.4.2 ) International -> Translations -> Copy language not working

Tags: prestashop

I need help to copy prestashop language from one language to another language.
I am using Prestashop 1.7.4.2 with warehouse theme

When i try to copy From English to any other language it gives me error 
"theme doesn't exists"

Currently I'm using warehouse theme.

Can anyone help me to understand issue and solution ?

[image]
[image]

Comment: I think that’s because there is no physical files of `english`.

Comment: @Rolige Can you guide me process to do that manually ? Basically I want to copy all menu & cms content from one language (english) to all other languages.

Comment: Let me tell you that copy a language doesn't include that kind of content, its only about the translations you make from the translations tab, not content like product, category, cms, etc. You will need do that manually.